# Retrieve latest twitter tweet with a particular hashtag via CLI

Tags: bash, shell, twitter, hashtag

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the latest tweet that contains a particular twitter hashtag via the cli (bash).  Something that would run like: "./get-tweet.sh blah" and return "Dude I'm feeling so #blah"  Thanks!

Looks like I can get the rss feed by doing this:

curl -s 'http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=%23blah&rpp=1'

I would then just need to cut out the correct xml

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at [TTYtter](http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/) for doing that. In particular it allows for scripting like so:

```
ttytter -runcommand="/search #haiku"
```

You'll need to do the initial setup interactively though for oAuth.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I hacked together a solution:

## !/bin/bash

curl -s "http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=%23$1&rpp=1" > /tmp/hashtag.xml

xmllint --xpath '/rss/channel/item/title/text()' /tmp/hashtag.xml | sed 's/http\://t.co/*//g' | sed 's/#//g' | sed 's/@//g' |xargs -i -0 echo -n "{}"
echo

rm /tmp/hashtag.xml

Comment: The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.